# Replace datagrid values?

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid

Hi I am trying to overwrite the value in a datagrid I have with a new one. I tried the following code:

```
datagrid1.addItem({Column1: "support"});
```

And this causes the new value to be added to the row below it instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What data grid are you using?

Comment: Is this using Flex? You should add that tag too so potential helpers know what you mean. Is there such a thing as `( {Column0: "support"} )`??

Comment: I'm just using the normal datagrid for as3. It's not using flex. And 'column1' is the name of the column, while 'support' is the new value to be inputted

Comment: DataGrid (dg) have a dataProvider (dp) - you have to change data in dp, then refresh the dg, [dp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/data/DataProvider.html)